# Amazon aws missing dlls (MSVCP140, VCRUNTIME140, CONCRT140)

Tags: c++, windows, amazon-web-services, dll

I made an web server app, that should reside on amazon aws vitual machine with win10.
When i trying execute this app, it says that it missing dlls (MSVCP140, VCRUNTIME140, CONCRT140)
In the app i use cpprestsdk, cryptocpp, opencv.

I try to install various visual C++ redistributables, but its not gave the result.
Downloaded this dlls separately and put it into system32 foled ,but either no result.
When i put dlls in app folder it gave me the error that app was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b).
Tryed to execute app builded with /MT flag (it actually dont remove all the dlls) and problem is still there

Amazon instance type is t2.micro

Comment: 0xc0000007b could be indicative of using the wrong architecture of the MS VCRT redistributable.

Comment: @Botje Yeah this is it. Thank another time!